# dataframe missing the header, after restricting original structure with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

python 3.7.2. in pycharm/jupyter
I was loading an excel sheet to a dataframe with the common pandas/read_excel
this part worked perfectly.
The headed is in the first line both in the excel file and also the loaded df.
After wanted to create a secondary table out of it, by applying filters (including only the first 20 rows, and only a part of the columns.
The code runs through, however it returns a dataframe which has no header, but only numbers instead of the column names

as far as I understand the header, is by default loaded in the pandas package, unless I exclude it. I tried many different scenarios but none worked.

```
df = pd.read_excel('resources//ifilename.xlsx', parse_dates=    [['TIME_STAMP', 'Starting_Date', 'Expiry_Date']])
Z = df.iloc[:20 , 6:26].values
```

I want to have the headers also in the secondary dataframe, and understand what did I do wrong with this very simple code.

Comment: please give us sample data in ifilename.xlsx. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifically asking it not to return the column names when you call `.values` in your line `df.iloc[].values`

If you want the same info with the column names, try `Z = df.iloc[:20 , 6:26]`